# Future Function passed as parameter not executing Flutter

Tags: flutter, parameter-passing, future

I am trying to create a widget from a custom Widget, so when I pass the parameters to the function that creates the Widget I need to set the onPressed function but dosen´t work when pressing it.

Class A:

```
final Future Function(BuildContext context, Key newKey, String title) myFunction = _functionToPass;
setState(() {
    _widgetList.add(_MyCustomWidget.createCustomWidget(_title, _isChecked, myFunction));
  });//This works, the widget appears on my screen.

  Future _functionToPass(BuildContext context, Key newKey, String taskTitle) =>
  showDialog(......);
```

Class B:

```
class MyCustomWidget {
  StatefulBuilder createCustomWidget(title, isChecked, myFunction) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(title),
            leading: Checkbox(
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  isChecked = newValue!;
                });
              },
            ),
            trailing: TextButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () async {
                print("Hi"); //This is printing correctly
                await myFunction; //the function is not calling
              },
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You need to call your function by adding the parentheses to it, and passing the required parameters:

```
onPressed: () async {
  print("Hi");
  await myFunction(param1, param2...);   //Change this line
},
```

#### Sample for Reproducing the Issue:

Try running the code below on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/), with and without the parentheses:

```
void main() async {
  final Future Function(String title) myFunction = (String title) async{print(title);};
  print("Hi");
  await myFunction("a");
}
```

Also, as discussed in the comments, it's a good practice to specify the expected function with parameters on the method handle, instead os just naming the parameters, add the type, like this:

```
StatefulBuilder createCustomWidget(title, isChecked, Future Function(BuildContext, Key, String) myFunction)
```

So when you pass the wrong parameters, Dart knows it is wrong and warns you:

[image: Sample error with wrong parameters]

Comment: Thanks it worked, I don´t tried with () because the solutions that I found were like I the one that I tried without(), so when the function has parameters it goes with() and without() otherwise?

Comment: Also, the function is getting called  because the dialog showed but is not updating the state. Do you know how to update the state? I thought that with StatefulBuilder() but the class A is not getting updated. @George

Comment: I believe you would need the empty parentheses in any case, but you need to add the parameters requried by your function. If you want to see the errors, it is usually a best practice to specify the function type on the parameters. Instead of just writing `StatefulBuilder createCustomWidget(title, isChecked, myFunction) {`, you could use `StatefulBuilder createCustomWidget(title, isChecked, Function(String) myFunction) {`. So you get an error on compilation. I'll add details to my answer